# How do we view and resolve the difference between my version and the server version of a file?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, onedrive, version-control, cloud

In our MS Office Upload Center, I have a file:

- **Name** MyFile.docx
- **Location** d.docs.live.net/2234hksjdfhk2j34/Documents/Work/ (this is OneDrive)
- **Last in Sync** 10/26/2014 2:50 PM
- **Status** Please Refresh

In the Upload Center, when I right click `Refresh`, nothing happens. I.e. the status still says, "Please Refresh." When I right click on the file listing, there's an "Open to Resolve" optio. When I do that, MS Word opens the file with a warning.

> UPLOAD FAILED: We're sorry, someone updated the server copy and it's not possible to upload your changes now. (Keep My Version) (Keep Server Version).

How can we view (and possibly resolve/merge) the differences between my version and server version?

For now, I just chose "Keep My Version", in which case my version uploaded to the server, and the file vanished from the MS Office Upload Center.

Comment: Office Online is having a difficult time converting the document to a web version. OneDrive is real buggy when it comes to synchronizing Office files in this situation. If you know there's been no changes, then you can just re-save. Other times, I've had to save as a different document, then erase the old document.